# How to set up Reply from email on Apple Mail?

Tags: mail.app

I'm experiencing trouble with my Apple Mail app. I've multiple mail accounts configured on it and when I'm replying from any of them, app displays correct value in From field. But just after I send it, in the Sent catalogue appears absolute different (other account's) From email address in that message. And people always get my mail from that one account no matter what I set in the From field when writing. Do you have any ideas what is wrong, what should I do? By the way, I'm using Yosemite OS.

Comment: Check the SMTP settings for the accounts. Perhaps you're sending over the wrong SMTP server

Answer (score 1):

Solving this could actually be as simple as changing one of the preferences:

Apple mail > preferences > composing

..check if "*Send new messages from*" is set to "*Account of selected mailbox*"

[image]